# Fast way to convert a hexadecimal string to hexadecimal char array

Tags: c, string, qt, hex

I need to convert string which contain hexadecimal number to unsigned char array.

I have this code in QT:

```
QString data
...
QByteArray byteArray;
int bufSize = (data.length()) / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++)
   {
   byteArray[i] = data.mid(2*i, 2).toInt(NULL, 16);//Read the string two characters at a time.
   }
```

I need to do the same action in C and I don't know how to convert it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: if you already have `hexadecimal string` then you can use `sprintf()` to convert this to char array...I think it is the fastest way.

Answer (score 6):

The fastest method is with a lookup array:

```
int cvt[UCHAR_MAX+1] = {0};
cvt['0'] = 0;
cvt['1'] = 1;
// ...
cvt['9'] = 9;
cvt['a'] = 10;
// ...
cvt['f'] = 15;
cvt['A'] = 10;
// ...
cvt['F'] = 15;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof arr; i++) {
    arr[i] = 16 * cvt[(unsigned char)data[2*i]] +
                  cvt[(unsigned char)data[2*i + 1]];
}
```

Comment: The code above works for hexadecimal strings with even number of hexadecimal digits. You need to tweak it if you need odd-numbered hexadecimal strings.

Comment: `"ab"` is 171; `"5c"` is 92; apparently your computer interprets `171` as '«' and `92` as '\' (ASCII?).

Comment: +1 for a certainly a fast method.  BTW: Suspect you wanted `cvt[CHAR_MAX+1]` but I would suggest `cvt[UCHAR_MAX+1]` and `cvt[(unsigned char) data[2*i]]`

Comment: Yes @chux, thank you; post edited. The array doesn't need `+1` however

Comment: @pmg `UCHAR_MAX` is often 255, yet there are typically 256 different `char`, codes 0 to 255.  Still recommend +1.  But I do see the a value of '\0' is not likely to be referenced.

Comment: Oops ... my bad, thank you @chux. You are most definitely right.

Answer (score 0):

I found faster way:

```
char temp[3]={0};
char* p=data;
int bufSize = (strlen(data)) / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i++,p+=2)
{
    //Read the string two characters at a time.
    arr[i]=(unsigned char)(strtol(strncpy(temp,p,2),NULL,16));
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: "Faster" than what? Avoiding the repeated calls to `strtol` and `strncpy` surely would be faster.

Answer (score -1):

use `sprintf()` for fastest convertion from `hexadecimal string` to `hexadecimal char array`.

```
char buffer[USER_DIFINED_LENGTH];
sprintf(buffer,"%s", your_data);
```

here USER_DIFINED_LENGTH is the length which can hold your data.

for more information on `sprintf()` check http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf

Comment: with this you'll just copy one string to another.